# Android MultipartEntity.getContentType().getName() and MultipartEntity.getContentType().getValue() methods not found

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-6.0-marshmallow, multipartentity

I have an issue while using multipart to upload post data to server.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-length", reqEntity.getContentLength() +"");
conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(),reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());
```

This thing works fine when I use the following in the build.gradel

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valuelabs.fup"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

when the target version is changed to 23 and compileSdkVersion is changed to 23 which is the latest,

```
conn.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(),reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());
```

This line is throwing error saying getName and getValue methods are not found,

How should i solve this issue, what are the alternate methods to these methods. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: asked bazillion times: apache http client library was removed from framework

Comment: yes but what is the solution? simply down voting the question doesn't answer the question. I have tried many things like useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy', but still it doesn't help me.

Comment: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` where did you put this?

Comment: android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.valuelabs.fup"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

Comment: which com.android.tools.build version ? which version of apache mime?

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.valuelabs.fup"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: this was the unedited code that caused problem

Comment: @Selvin i added compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'

Comment: Hi @Selvin I have tried with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' but here it says the MultipartEntity is depricated and can't access it

Comment: I have solved it using org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;

Comment: For your sanity it would be better choose different http client library ... I was using apache for long time but now I'm choosing okhttp

Comment: Thank you @Selvin will consider your advice